# React/Next.js + Firebase: how to refresh the page for all users on a particular URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on a Next.js application with a Firebase backend and I have the following set up: a user can create a session that other people can join, but only the creator can "start" the session (trigger a state change). When this stage change occurs, I want to refresh the browsers of all users in this session.

When a user creates a session, they are redirected to `pages/[sessionId]` and a new session is created in Firebase (real-time DB). My `pages/[sessionId]` has a switch statement that looks at the state of the session ID (whether it has been started or not) and it displays a component based on this.

Here is what I've considered so far:

- I could technically use the `useRouter` hook and reload the page, but that would only reload the page for one user who triggered this change, whereas I want to do this for everyone.
- My next thought was Firebase cloud functions to somehow trigger a state change signal, but Firebase has no idea who is connected to my session
- Then I thought that Next.js comes with Server-Side-Rendering (even though I understand that SSR isn't meant to provide backend functionality), so perhaps there could be a way to accomplish it with pure Next.js, but I've got no idea how

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own, it turned out to be quite simple. For anyone else who might be stuck, here is what I did: inside of my `useEffect`, I have a function that fetches the current session state and then inside a `then` clause, I have another function that makes use of the `onValue` function from Firebase, so as soon as the state changes, it triggers another function call that is performed for all users.